# How can I create a customized receive activity in WF?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I would like to create a WF receive activity but customized to use a fixed contract and fixed parameters. I have thought in extending the Receive activity and set some of it properties, but it is a sealed class.

Which is the best aproach to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your designer can use an IActivityTemplateFactory to pre-configure the existing Send/Receive with the contract you want.  You can also add variables that may be required.  That way developers won't have to type in each of the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You create a XAML activity and drop the Receive activity in there. If you add a service reference to a workflow project that is exactly what the tooling does when it generates the prepackaged activities for you.

Comment: Thanks Maurice, I was waiting for you :).

That way I could not create a sendresponse related to the receive, or at least I haven't found the way. I want the programmers to just drag and drop the receive and being able to create the response wherever they want, with a logic in the middle. I have tried with code activities and custom designers for the middle activities, but I have given up.

Comment: You can add a SendResponse inside the same activity. Do an Add Service Reference and check the generated activities.

Comment: Yes, I have done what you said. But I want the logic in the middle of the receive and response, not after the response.